# How to open HDFS output file using gedit?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, gedit, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed and executed an mapreduce program successfully in my system(Ubuntu 14.04).

I can see the output file as,

```
hadoopuser@arul-PC:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -ls /user/hadoopuser/MapReduceSample-output
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoopuser supergroup          0 2014-07-09 16:10 /user/hadoopuser/MapReduceSample-output/_SUCCESS
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoopuser supergroup          0 2014-07-09 16:10 /user/hadoopuser/MapReduceSample-output/_logs
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoopuser supergroup     880838 2014-07-09 16:10 /user/hadoopuser/MapReduceSample-output/part-00000
```

And I can open it on terminal using following command,

```
hadoopuser@arul-PC:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -cat /user/hadoopuser/MapReduceSample-output/part-00000
```

I can see the output file on terminal, but I can't see the full result because my output has large amount of lines.

So I want to open it on `gedit` or `nano`.

Need Solution.

Comment: The way you have currently worded your question, it is off-topic for stackoverflow. The problem is that you are asking for an off-site resource ("Where can I get ..."). If you instead asked something like "How do I set up Eclipse for hadoop development", it would be on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access HDFS file from local machine(system user), so that you can't open HDFS file using `gedit`.

To open in `gedit` you have to *copy* to local machine.

To do that, open terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and use `copyToLocal` a **Hadoop Shell Command** to copy the output file into local machine.

Do the following,

```
hadoopuser@arul-PC:/usr/local/hadoop$ sudo bin/hadoop dfs -copyToLocal /user/hadoopuser/MapReduceSample-output/part-00000 /home/arul/Downloads/
```

Now you can open the output file using `gedit` as follows,

```
$ sudo gedit /home/arul/Downloads/part-00000
```

**Note :**

1. My **HDFS** username is `hadoopuser`.
2. You can move a file from **HDFS** to local machine. The **Hadoop Shell Command** `fs -mv` allow to move different HDFS location.
3. For more **[Hadoop Shell Commands(click here)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html)**.

**Update** (*An another option to do the same from [Y-Prithvi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3355533/y-prithvi)'s post*)

you can also use getmerge to copy HDFS file to local system.

```
hadoopuser@arul-PC:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -getmerge /user/hadoopuser/MapReduceSample-output/part-00000 /home/arul/MROutput

hadoop dfs -getmerge /path/to/HDFS /path/to/save
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also use `getmerge` to copy HDFS file to local system.

```
hadoopuser@arul-PC:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -getmerge /user/hadoopuser/MapReduceSample-output/part-00000 /home/arul/MROutput
```

`hadoop dfs -getmerge /path/to/HDFS /path/to/save`

Comment: it will concatenates the HDFS file into local file, your answer shows `/home/arul/MROutput` is a path, not a file. So it will not work, if you want to use `getmerge` you need to use empty local file to merge HDFS file. To get the same result `copyToLocal` is best one.

Comment: It works but yes, it concatenates. we can use `get` instead of `getmerge` in this case.

Comment: but for `get` and `getmerge` the destination must be a **file** your answer said a **path**, please take a look in your answer...

Comment: If there is no file in that path it will one. In my answer it'll create a file called MROutput and copies the HDFS file.

Comment: Ok Ok, I thought MROutput was a folder... let me update your info in answer and I will upvote yours, thank you...

Answer (score 1):

instead of looking for plugin. You can add jar files from $HADOOP_INSTALL/bin in eclipse and compiler issues must be gone.

Comment: there is no jar files in 'bin'

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Setup for Hadoop Development

[this](http://boharag.blogspot.hk/2013/11/eclipse-setup-for-hadoop-development.html) should help

Comment: I am using hadoop-2.4.0, this is not helpful for me.. I already saw like this tutorial.. for hadoop-1.0.4