# gedit to create sql file

Tags: hdfs, hiveql, gedit

I am using cloudera VM 5x.
In the HDFS terminal, I am using the below command to create a sql file.

```
gedit /user/cloudera/sample.sql
```

It is in edit mode, when I am saving, it is throwing an error "Could not find the file /user/cloudera/sample.sql."

What's wrong with it? Even I tried to provide the full path

```
gedit hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/sample.sql
```

This is also returning an error saying "Could not open the file hdfs://quickstart.cloude…ser/cloudera/sample.sql." along with "gedit cannot handle hdfs: locations."

What is supposed to be the command here?

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open HDFS output file using gedit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653645/how-to-open-hdfs-output-file-using-gedit)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it.

```
gedit /user/cloudera/sample.sql
```

This will not work since gedit saves the file into local file system and /user/cloudera is HDFS path.